# How to derive joint CDF Gumbel distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, joint-distribution, gumbel-distribution

If you have 3 random variables: $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ and they have independent Gumbel distribution. $A$, $B$ and $C$ are three discrete random variables that are functions of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ as per the following relationships:
$$\begin{cases}
A=1 \text{ if $X≤x$, $A=0$ otherwise}\\
B=1 \text{ if $Y≤y$, $B=0$ otherwise}\\
C=1 \text{ if $Z≤z$, $C=0$ otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
$$
a) What is the joint probability $$Pr(A=1, B=1, C=1)$$

I wanted to confirm if this is accurate:

Joint pdf 
$$\exp[-\exp(-μ_1(x-η_1))].\exp[-\exp(-μ_2(y-η_2))].\exp[-\exp(-μ_3(z-η_3))]$$

My reasoning for a) is since X, Y and Z are independent, you can multiply the joint pdf.

b) What is the joint pdf if there is a constraint: $(x+y+z)≤K$?

I am not sure how to solve b. The only idea I have is the ranges of X, Y, Z changed with the new constraint.

Would appreciate your thoughts on a) and b :)

Comment: Please add `self-study` as a tag and detail your reasoning for a) and your jamming point for b).

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Answer (score 1):

$$Pr(A=1, B=1, C=1) = \exp[-\exp(-μ_1(x-η_1))].\exp[-\exp(-μ_2(y-η_2))].\exp[-\exp(-μ_3(z-η_3))]$$ is joint probability, not joint pdf.

Let $p_i = \exp[−\exp(−μ_i(x−η_i))]$, i =1, 2,  3. Then the joint pdf of $A, B, C$ is 
$$\Pr(A,B,C) = p_1^A(1-p_1)^{(1-A)}p_2^B(1-p_2)^{(1-B)}p_3^C(1-p_3)^{(1-C)} \quad \text{for} A,B,C = 0 \text{ or } 1 $$

For the constraint $(x+y+z)≤K$, get $$\Pr[(x+y+z)≤K] = \int\int\int_{(x+y+z)≤K}\exp[-\exp(-μ_1(x-η_1))].\exp[-\exp(-μ_2(y-η_2))].\exp[-\exp(-μ_3(z-η_3))]dxdydz$$

The joint pdf with a constraint $(x+y+z)≤K$ is

$$\frac {\Pr(A,B,C)}{\Pr[(x+y+z)≤K]} $$ with range of $A,B,C = 0 \text{ or } 1$ and constraint $(x+y+z)≤K$.